# Coding logistic SGD manually in a for loop in Python -- am I interpreting this correctly?

Tags: python, torch

I'm following the steps of SGD, but unsure if I am interpreting the steps correctly.

Let's say there are two w terms:

[image: equation1]

where `x` is tensors and `w` are two logistic function params.

[image: equation2]

and the goal is to find `argmin(lambda)`

And SGD formula is given as:

[image: equation3]

This is the code I have so far, with library constraints:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

some_data = torch.rand(1000, 2)
x = some_data[:,0]
y = (x + 0.4 * some_data[:,1] > 0.5).to(torch.int) # doesn't work with bool?

x = torch.split(x, 3) # batch
y = torch.split(y, 3)

# optim problem
w1 = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.tensor([0.1]), requires_grad=True)
w2 = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.tensor([0.1]), requires_grad=True)

lambda_min = torch.zeros(1)

for epoch in range(10):
  #print(f'epoch: ', epoch)
  for xx, yy in zip(x, y):
    
    p_x = 1 / (1 + torch.exp(-w1 - (torch.mul(w2, x))))
    
    # NLL
    lambda = torch.sum(yy * torch.log(p_x) + (1 + yy) * torch.log(1 - p_x))
    
    # Gradient???
    if lambda < lambda_min :
      lambda_min = lambda # Q: loss value, right?
      # Q: update params...?
      w2 = w1 - torch.mul(0.01, lambda_min)
      print(f'w2 = ', w2)
    else:
      pass
```

I would like to confirm the parts with "Q:"
Then how would I plot this with `y` and `x` to look like a regular logistic function with tensors, similar to below, but with all the 1s and 0s in the graph?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with this code.

1. You never calculate any gradients, so this is not *gradient* descent.
2. Gradient descent updates values of parameters *always*, not just when `lambda < lambda_min`. BTW, `lambda` is a keyword and can't be used as a variable name.
3. `w2 = w1 - torch.mul(0.01, lambda_min)` is *not* a gradient descent step:

   1. Gradient descent sets new `w2` equal to old `w2` plus some adjustment. You code sets it equal to `w1` (!) plus some adjustment.
   2. That adjustment is supposed to be the scaled negative gradient. In your code it's the scaled *value of the loss function*, which it not the gradient.
4. According to your logistic function formula, `(1 + yy) * torch.log(1 - p_x)` should be `(1 - yy) * torch.log(1 - p_x)` (note the "`1` *minus* `yy`" part).